# Go: JSON marshalling nested struct; incorrectly omitting outer fields

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal nested structs. See a NON-FUNCTIONING example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/7TeQO2pWsx) (I can't import "compute" and "pretty" in the Go playground, but I've recreated my test logic and pasted the output).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/kylelemons/godebug/pretty"
    compute "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
)

type CreateInstance struct {
    compute.Instance

    // Additional metadata to set for the instance.
    Metadata map[string]string `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    // OAuth2 scopes to give the instance. If none are specified
    // https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only will be added.
    Scopes []string `json:",omitempty"`

    // StartupScript is the Sources path to a startup script to use in this step.
    // This will be automatically mapped to the appropriate metadata key.
    StartupScript string `json:",omitempty"`
    // Project to create the instance in, overrides workflow Project.
    Project string `json:",omitempty"`
    // Zone to create the instance in, overrides workflow Zone.
    Zone string `json:",omitempty"`
    // Should this resource be cleaned up after the workflow?
    NoCleanup bool
    // Should we use the user-provided reference name as the actual resource name?
    ExactName bool

    // The name of the disk as known internally to Daisy.
    daisyName string
}

func main() {
    ci := <a *CreateInstance part of a larger data structure>
    j, _ := json.MarshalIndent(ci, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(j))
    pretty.Print(ci)  # Pretty prints the struct.
}


##### OUTPUT #####
{
  "disks": [
    {
      "source": "disk"
    }
  ],
  "machineType": "${machine_type}",
  "name": "${instance_name}"
}
{Instance:      {CanIpForward:      false,
                 CpuPlatform:       "",
                 CreationTimestamp: "",
                 Description:       "",
                 Disks:             [{AutoDelete:        false,
                                      Boot:              false,
                                      DeviceName:        "",
                                      DiskEncryptionKey: nil,
                                      Index:             0,
                                      InitializeParams:  nil,
                                      Interface:         "",
                                      Kind:              "",
                                      Licenses:          [],
                                      Mode:              "",
                                      Source:            "disk",
                                      Type:              "",
                                      ForceSendFields:   [],
                                      NullFields:        []}],
                 Id:                0,
                 Kind:              "",
                 MachineType:       "${machine_type}",
                 Metadata:          nil,
                 Name:              "${instance_name}",
                 NetworkInterfaces: [],
                 Scheduling:        nil,
                 SelfLink:          "",
                 ServiceAccounts:   [],
                 Status:            "",
                 StatusMessage:     "",
                 Tags:              nil,
                 Zone:              "",
                 ServerResponse:    {HTTPStatusCode: 0,
                                     Header:         {}},
                 ForceSendFields:   [],
                 NullFields:        []},
 Metadata:      {},
 Scopes:        [],
 StartupScript: "",
 Project:       "",
 Zone:          "",
 NoCleanup:     false,
 ExactName:     false}
```

Basically, I have a struct, CreateInstance, that embeds an Instance struct from the [Google Compute Engine API client lib](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1#Instance). CreateInstance also has two bool fields with no JSON tags, ExactName and NoCleanup.

When I try to marshal a CreateInstance, ExactName and NoCleanup are omitted, be they true or false.

Comment: Here's an approximation in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9R9Yo8IemD  It works as expected.  Does MarshalIndent return an error?

Comment: Good approximation. No, MashalIndent does not return an error.

Comment: So, I'm currently passing in a *CreateInstance. When I deref it, it works.

Comment: No, this is more like what's happening: https://play.golang.org/p/6RCsQ3AM03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `compute.Instance` is a `json.Marshaler`, so by embedding that type you are in essence giving your `CreateInstance` the `MarshalJSON` method from `compute.Instance`, which of course isn't going to output any of the fields in your `CreateInstance` struct.

You could define your own `MarshalJSON` method, and try to marshal the `Instance` manually or re-assign it to a new type that will use the default json output, but the API may be relying on the internal `MarshalJSON` behavior, so that's not guaranteed to be compatible, currently or with future versions.

Embedding types for json marshaling is is best avoided because it's all too easy to create confusing bugs like this. I would try to compose them in a different manner.

Comment: Hey thank you! Unfortunately, trying to "compose them in a different manner" is a bit difficult since we want to expose a JSON config schema to users. Embedding is nicer than an inner compute.Instance instance or pointer in the JSON config, since an inner compute.Instance would require a nested object.